# Get data from tables with one to one relation for API in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-5

I'm working on my first Laravel project, and I want to create a REST Api for android application. In my system, I have two tables: `categories` and `images`. Table `images` has column `category_id` which is a foreign key that references column `id` on `category` table.

#### The `categories` table

```
    //users table migration
    class CreateCategoriessTable extends Migration
    {
        public function up()
        {
         Schema::create('categories', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->increments('id');
         $table->string('name');
         $table->timestamps();
        });
       }
...
    }
```

#### The `images` table

```
class CreateImagesTable extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('images', function(Blueprint $table){
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name')
            $table->integer('category_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('category_id')
                ->references('id')
                ->on('categories')
                ->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

In the `Images` model class I did it:

```
class Images extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
    protected $hidden = array('created_at', 'updated_at');

    public function category(){
        $this->belongsTo('App\Category');
    }
}
```

I also created `CategoryResource()` class as:

```
class CategoryResource extends JsonResource

    {
          public function toArray($request)
        {
        return [
            'id'=> $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
        ];
        }
    }
```

So, I created a `CategoryController` to with the API methods, and configured the routes to access the corresponding function. The `api/category/` url via `GET` is redirect to the `index` function of my controller, and the function is like that:

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::get();
    return CategoryResource::collection($categories);
}
```

With this, I can get the `categories` table data, but I would like merge the `users` and `images` table, and get something like this as response:

```
[
   {
      'id': 1,
      'name': 'category_name',
      'image': 'image_name'
   }
]
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a `hasOne` relation in `Category` model for image like this

Category Model

```
public function image(){  
    return $this->hasOne('App\Image');
}
```

Now specify the relation in your `CategoryResource`

```
class CategoryResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'=> $this->id,
            'name' => $this->name,
            'image' => new ImageResource($this->whenLoaded('image'))
        ];
    }
}
```

Create `ImageResource` for loading images

```
class ImageResource extends JsonResource
{
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
            'id'=> $this->id,
            'name' => $this->image_name,
        ];
    }
}
```

Finally load `images` relations with eager load in your controller like this

```
public function index()
{
    $categories = Category::with('image')->get();
    return CategoryResource::collection($categories);
}
```

Comment: @Dexter i miss read your question. If you need for one to one then just add a hasOne relation in category model and change accordingly in resourse class. just because of that i got down vote. I wil update my answer so that future user will not have problem

Comment: @Dexter updated answer based on `hasOne` relation. Thanks for your understanding and accepted my answer. Happy coding